# How to change the arrow image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to animate the image **left to right** with **arrow key image** based on animate the arrow need to change the direction. this is the code I have tried but not working properly help!.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".FloorPlanArrow").click(function() {
    $(".pano-floorplan").animate({
      right: '-225px'
    }, 250);

    if (true) {
      $('.FloorPlanArrow').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'
      });
      $(".FloorPlanArrow").click(function() {
        $(".pano-floorplan").animate({
          right: '0px'
        }, 250);
      });
    } else {
      $('.FloorPlanArrow').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[ArrowChange](https://jsfiddle.net/kumareshrajalingam/ob1rk2zj/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "It's not working properly". It's like saying "I have some kind of problem"

Comment: Please review your post and improve it so it is easy to get what you asked for.

Comment: `if(true)`....? Your fiddle is also missing jQuery

Comment: Is this what your looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/ob1rk2zj/1/

Comment: https://livetour.istaging.com/57ecd104816dfa005668e914  see the floor plan image I need like this

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to achieve but if you just want to flip the arrow left/right, you would be be better off using `scaleX(-1)`: https://jsfiddle.net/ob1rk2zj/2/

Comment: Updated it now, you should also use position: absolute on your section element https://jsfiddle.net/ob1rk2zj/3/

Comment: Thanks  Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: how to use co ordinates in jquery? means move one posx to posY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to handle the animation via CSS and then toggle the class on the element via a script.

If you do employ this approach, it's as easy to script using standard javascript as it is to use the jQuery library.

---

### This approach using jQuery:

```js
$('p').click(function(){
    $('p').toggleClass('reverse');
});
```

```css
p {
margin-top: 0;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 64px;
transition: transform 0.6s linear;
cursor: pointer;
}

p.reverse {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Click the arrow...</h2>
<p>&larr;</p>
```

---

### This approach using standard javascript:

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function reverseArrow() {
 paragraph.classList.toggle('reverse');
}

paragraph.addEventListener('click', reverseArrow, false);
```

```css
p {
margin-top: 0;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 64px;
transition: transform 0.6s linear;
cursor: pointer;
}

p.reverse {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>Click the arrow...</h2>
<p>&larr;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I udnderstand, create a varible with intial angle degrees and then loop it

```
var angle = 0
while(angle <= 180){
   $(".floorPlanArrow").rotate(angle);
   angle++;
}
```

OR,

```
    $(".floorPlanArrow").rotate({bind:{
       click: function(){
        $(this).rotate({
          angle: 0,
          animateTo:180
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this is it what you meant.